# Trigger scroll event in UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, ios7, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that has a few images in it and does:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Load the pages that are now on screen
    [self loadVisiblePages:NO page_index:0];
}
```

Now, I want to be able to initiate a scrolling the images by clicking the page control component on the page. 
Any way to trigger a scroll event that would call the function above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several, but I am not sure, why you don't just call the method directly?

But you could call

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:<#(CGRect)#> animated:YES];
```

and also

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:<#(CGPoint)#> animated:YES];
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Used the `scrollRectToVisible` option! Superb! Thanks